# Running a SQlite command from Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a following program sample in Java

```
String[] DB_IMPORT     =   {"sh","-c","sqlite3 a.db < ExportCommands.sh"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(DB_IMPORT);
```

ExportCommands.sh contains

```
attach database "test.db" as test;
create table test.t1 as select ID , NAME from thisTable;
```

thisTable is present in a.db , and I am try to import some columns from a.db to test.db. test.db is already present with no table.
When I run this command from console it can import the data but can't import if I run from Java. Whats going wrong here ?

Comment: What error are you getting?